# a Kafka Stream back to itself

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have just defined a KStreams topology for the first time and wanted a quick sanity check to make sure I'm not doing something stupid (or if there's a better way.) Essentially what I have boils down to:

```
[input-topic] --> alltime-store
              --> thisweek-store --> (logic) --> {new-record} -->[input-topic]
```

Records are read from the input-topic and then `groupBy()` and `Materialized` onto two separate counting stores.

The `thisweek-store` is `windowedBy` a specific time duration and passed onto a `filter` that applies some logic, which an example might be:

```
if value > 10
  then send new-record
```

If it's not obvious, at a very high level, I am trying to award a bonus if somebody does something enough times in one week.

Is it OK to create a cycle like this in your topology?

The only obvious problem I can see is you might create an infinite loop; but hopefully this could be prevented in the [logic] block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use the `Streams.to()` output topic as `builder.stream()` input topic in the same application.

As there can be valid scenarios i.e. reinforcement learning. If you are training some data where you produce newer events based on previous one.

Comment: What about if I sent the new record directly to the alltime-store? Something like `...stream.to("alltime-store-repartition")`

Comment: there is nothing wrong in doing that but make sure that it is user topic, not the internal topic (as you referred example name with `-repartition`. Those are short lived topics and cleaned up after application is reset.